# PHP - Insert to database without refresh page ( OOP )

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to find a way how can I insert something to my MySQL database without refreshing the page and also don't make a security hole.

After some hours of trying and searching I have this:

```
<form name="form1" action="">
Enter Name <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1"></td> <br>
Enter City <input type="text" name="t2" id="t2"></td> <br>
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Insert to DB" onClick="aa()">
</form>
<div id="d1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function aa()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?name=" + document.getElementById("t1").value + "&city=" + document.getElementById("t2").value, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;;
}
</script>
```

Which is simple form, which call JS , and that JS redirect info to .php file where is SQL command for inserting things to database.

But I'm not sure if this is "secure" and also I would prefer to call some method which will insert (using MVC) or something like that.

Is here anybody who can give me some knowhow?

Comment: This is called AJAX. You'll want to urlencode the values you're sending to `insert.php` in case they put characters like `&` in the input fields. Security really depends on the code in `insert.php` more than the JS/HTML.

Comment: The question is: "Is XmlHttpRequest less secure than 'normal' request ?" . No. In both case do your check on the server side.

Comment: Where is the SQL-related code?

Comment: SQL code is in insert.php ? It's not importnat here, it's simple $_GET[] and insert. But how can i call a PHP method instead of redirecting to new file?

Comment: The question is legit. Not everybody knows about AJAX request ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is legitimate. A lot of websites are using this technique this day where a page communicates with a server without reloading the whole page, without sending full headers and reloading all resources. Is a very useful technique, pioneered by Microsoft some years ago and then adopted and supported by all browsers, with the advantage of being more user-friendly and faster. You can use your own code, like you did to create an AJAX request or use a library (like jQuery, DOJO, mootools, YUI, etc) that solve for you a lot of differences between browsers. In my opinion you should start by using a library as they have examples and will help you a lot at the beginning.

The infrastructure of an AJAX request is still the HTTP verbs: GET and POST mainly, used to get a new chunk of information or to save some input. This JavaScript part is like any other Javascript executed on clients side, in the client browser, which makes it insecure by default. The security rule is:

- **always check user input and distrust humans by default** :) - filter it, sanitize it, do a thousand checks before trusting it to be saved in your database or before using it anywhere.

This you have to do it on PHP side. Again, you can, filter yourself or you can use libraries or MVC that can help you with that. Here is a little more tricky in my opinion to recommend something. Sometimes those come with a lot of extra information and may introduce more headaches.

Learn how the things work by experimenting with a JS library and a simple PHP script and later you can move from there.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a 'ajax' request. If you [google](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp) for that term you will find some interesting examples.

You might wanne consider using a library, for example jquery, which basicly abstracted it to a nice [function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are asking for is security. As said before, if you don't want to reload the page your option is AJAX, but if your main issue is security, then you have to implement [CSRF](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Site_Request_Forgery) (Cross-Site Request Forgery). To avoid csrf, you should check [this link](http://es.wikihow.com/evitar-ataques-CSRF-(falsificaci%C3%B3n-de-petici%C3%B3n-en-sitios-cruzados)-con-PHP).